# iOS: Debugging not working in XCode

Tags: xcode, debugging, ios

I'm using `XCode 4` and `iOS SDK 4.3.`
My debugging worked fine but now i discovered that when setting a breakpoint, the app pauses but XCode doesn't focus on the line in the Editor. Also the green arrow is not displayed when hitting the break point.
I have a `UINavigationController` which is allocated in the `AppDelegate`. When i set a breakpoint in the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` everything works as expected:

[image]

This is when i a breakpoint has paused the app in the mapViewController which is the first item added to the navigation controller. (No green arrow but app is paused):

[image]

I really have no clue why debugging is working in AppDelegate but not in this controller.
If you need additional info or screenshots in order to help me, please tell me.

***UPDATE:***

Now it's even not working in `AppDelegate` and changed nothing. I can also step through the lines and can see that values are assigned in the Locals and can therefore guess where the app is currently in the code. So obviously everything works, just the currently executed line is not marked as it should.

Comment: I thought I solved the problem by restarting XCode. At least debugging (showing the current executed line) works for 2-3 times. But then again its not showing the arrow and the current executed line. Odd, odd, odd

Answer (score 10):

In xCode4:

- Your Project Name -> Edit Scheme
- Info tab (in run configuration)
- Set Build Configuration to "Debug", Debugger - to "LLDB" ("GDB" was before)
- Run your project

Worked for me. For "LLDB" green line is visible. Switching back to "GDB" brings me to this issue again.

Comment: I installed xCode 4.0.2 to solve the problem (4.2 beta was before)

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem. XCode 4 just stops debugging but it doesn't display any errors. When I opened the SYSTEM console, I found this:

```
3/26/11 4:04:13 PM  Xcode[214]  [MT] Warning in /SourceCache/IDEDebugger/IDEDebugger-208/PlugIns/DebuggerGDB/DevToolsIDE/GDBMIDebuggingPlugin/GDBMI_Adaptor/PBXGDB_StackSequences.m:556
Details:  An unexpected error when executing stack-list-frames-lite : Previous frame inner to this frame (gdb could not unwind past this frame). Please attach your gdb log to your bug report.
Object:   <PBXGDB_UpdateStackSequence: 0x202a57b40>
Method:   -handleErrorForMICommand:
Thread:   <NSThread: 0x200020700>{name = (null), num = 1}
Please file a bug at http://bugreport.apple.com with this warning message and any useful information you can provide.
```

I have had this problem since XCode 3.2 and I have tried every solution I could find for it, but I have never been able to resolve it. At least XCode 3.2 told me the error. XCode 4 just stops working.

**Update:** sorry forgot the answer part. Several people have solved this problem by switching their compiler to GCC for the project AND ALL projects that it is linked to. Others have deleted their symbol file for their device version and XCode re-downloaded them and it started working. Niether work for me, but hopefully one will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the compiler: "GCC_VERSION = com.apple.compilers.llvmgcc42" to "GCC_VERSION = com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0"

Then compile and run again

Greetings